# How to specify an arbitrary percentage in the preview pane?

Tags: xcode

Xcode13.3.1 shows the options in the dropdown list, 6.25% - 400%, as shown the attached image.
Are there any way to get an arbitrary percentage like 60%?

The 2nd attached image showing 60% is captured at YouTube footage in 2021/09/20. Could the older version of Xcode indicate 60% preview display?

[Xcode preview pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIlZ5.png)
[image: Captured at YouTube]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from choosing predefined options, you can also use:

- "-" and "+" buttons next to it. It gives different results, because
  the step of these buttons is 25%
- Option + moving two fingers on the track pad. It allows to zoom at arbitrary value (there's a similar gesture if you use a mouse)
- The Editor -> Zoom menu item. It has plenty of other options, like Zoom to Fit

Comment: Solved! THX to your prompt response.

Option w/ pinch out gesture on the track pad is available for this issue.